# How do I fix the error "largeText is not defined"?, I'm not sure if i'm meant to define it at the start of the code

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a python game about dodging pieces of space junk while cruising around in a jet, for some reason though I am getting a NameError because the name "largeText" is not defined.

I've been creating this with the help of a tutorial and i'm not sure if I missed something important.

This is for an Software Design and Development HSC course assessment task.

There was meant to be smallText as well but that also comes up with a NameError of it not being defined.

```
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smalltext = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold.tff', 20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects("GO!", largeText)
    textRect.center = ((x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold.ttf',115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Space Dodgers!", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))

        button("GO!",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green)
        button("Quit!",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red)
```

Comment: You should post the exact error message with the stacktrace and also all relevant parts of your code, e.g. the `text_objects` function.

Comment: Some other things: in your `button` function, you create two variables `textSurf` and `textRect`, but you never use these. Instead, you use `TextSurf` and `TextRect`, which I guess is wrong. Also, you load your font three time each frame. Just load it once before enter your game loop.

Comment: Thanks sloth, definitely noted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [scopes and namespace](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

You define:

```
largeText = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold.ttf',115)
```

inside the `game_intro()` function.

Then in the `button()` function you use:

```
textSurf, textRect = text_objects("GO!", largeText)
```

I guess your error comes from this line. `button` does not know anything about variables defined inside other functions, hence you get a `NameError`.

> NameError: name 'largeText' is not defined

The general advice would be to pass whatever is needed by `button` as an argument of the function, but in your case however I think is a more simple error. You probably want to replace `largeText` with `smalltext` in the `button()` function, since you have defined `smalltext` just before:

```
textSurf, textRect = text_objects("GO!", smalltext)
```